# In Fortran,setting advance="no",but gets newline

Tags: fortran

I write code below which gets N the number of strings first and concate n strings,and print it. I set advance="no" option ,but it goes to newline.
I run this code in this site(https://yukicoder.me/problems/no/597)

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer::i,j,k,n
    character(1000)::str,ans
    read*,n
    do i=1,n
        read(*,'(a)')str
        str=trim(str)
        write(*,'(a)',advance='no')str
    end do
    print*,""
end program
```

Comment: The ```str=trim(str)`` has no effect, will place the trimmed string back in ```str``` and pad it with blanks. What is the effect when using ```write(*,'(a)',advance='no') trim(str)```? (I didn't test)

Comment: Thank you very much. write(*,"(a)",advance="no")trim(str) goes well !

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot get why the former one is wrong. Do you mean str=trim(str) does not change the length of str?

Comment: Correct because you store it again in ```str``` which remains to have a length of 1000. Contrary to e.g. C. Fortran does not have a termination character but fills the rest of the string with spaces.

Comment: I get it !!! Thank you !!!!

Comment: @Albert you should make that an answer

Comment: @agentp As requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `str=trim(str)` has no effect, it will place the trimmed string back in `str` and pad it with blanks (the length of `str` remains 1000). 
 Contrary to e.g. C. Fortran does not have a termination character but fills the rest of the string with spaces.
The omitting of the blanks at the end should be done when writing the string to the output so:

```
write(*,'(a)',advance='no') trim(str)
```